# default user not added to docker group, have to do su $USER?

Tags: linux, docker

I have Ubuntu 18.04. and after installing docker i added my user to docker group with the command

```
sudo usermod -aG docker ${USER}
```

and logged in

```
su - ${USER}
```

and if I check id, my user is added to docker group.

But when I reopen the terminal i cant do docker commands without **sudo** unless i explicitly do `su ${USER}`

also, I can't find docker group with the default user.
**What am I missing here?**

Comment: only do a restart.

Comment: Changes to group credentials don't affect your current session. You just need to log out and log back in; it's not necessary to restart.

Comment: yup! Thanks, it worked. Log out and log in.

P.S. why is it necessary?

Answer (score 1):

@larsks already replied to the main question in a comment, however I would like to elaborate on the implications of that change (adding your default user to the `docker` group).

Basically, the Docker daemon socket is owned by `root:docker`, so in order to use the Docker CLI commands, you need either to be in the `docker` group, or to prepend all `docker` commands by `sudo`.

As indicated in the [documentation of Docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/security/#docker-daemon-attack-surface), it is risky to follow the first solution on your personal workstation, because this just amounts to providing the default user with root permissions without `sudo`-like password prompt protection. Indeed, users in the `docker` group are *de facto* root on the host. See for example [this article](https://fosterelli.co/privilege-escalation-via-docker.html) and [that one](https://www.projectatomic.io/blog/2015/08/why-we-dont-let-non-root-users-run-docker-in-centos-fedora-or-rhel/).

Instead, you may want to follow the second solution, which can be somewhat simplified by adding to your `~/.bashrc` file an alias such as:

```
alias docker="sudo /usr/bin/docker"
```

Thus, `docker run --rm -it debian` will be automatically expanded to `sudo /usr/bin/docker run --rm -it debian`, thereby preserving `sudo`’s protection for your default user.